# Confusion between distinct and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I am confused on DISTINCT & GROUP BY in following scenario.

I have a table with columns `a - z`. I need to make a query with following conditions.

```
select DISTINCT a, b, c, d from table_name
```

But I need all the columns `a - z` from above query where I can `DISTINCT a, b, c, d`

So should I execute following query

```
select * from table_name GROUP BY a, b, c, d
```

I am confused between DISTINCT & GROUP BY in this case.

Can anybody please clear me

Thanks.

Comment: You should add sample data here.

Comment: Are you trying to get all distinct values from columns e-z for each unique instance of a-d?

Comment: I need to get all the columns which has distinct a-d

Comment: Sorry Tim i couldn't provide data for this question

Comment: This kind of problem is highly indicative of poor schema design.

Comment: @Strawberry  may be but I cannot change their schema :(

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a, b, c, d order by a) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Aggregation is not appropriate for this problem.  This query:

```
select *
from table_name 
group by a, b, c, d;
```

is syntactically incorrect -- and happily, MySQL no longer (by default settings) allows this syntax.  The problem is that you end up with unaggregated columns (such as `e`, `f`, and so on) in the `select`.  That is not allowed in SQL.  You need to be explicit with aggregation queries.